# Override Property with different compatible Type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, properties, .net-2.0

I need a base class with a property where I can derive classes with the same property but different (compatible) types. The base Class can be abstract.

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual object prop { get; set; }
}

public class StrBase : Base
{
    public override string prop { get; set; } // compiler error
}

public class UseIt
{
    public void use()
    {
        List<Base> l = new List<Base>();
        //...
    }
}
```

---

I tried it with Generics but that gives me a problem when using the class, because I want to store differently typed base classes in the List.

```
public class BaseG<T>
{
    public T prop { get; set; }
}

public class UseIt
{
    public void use()
    {
        List<BaseG> l = new List<BaseG>(); // requires type argument
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach to proposed solution:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Use();
    public abstract object GetProp();
}

public abstract class GenericBase<T> : Base
{
    public T Prop { get; set; }

    public override object GetProp()
    {
        return Prop;
    }
}

public class StrBase : GenericBase<string>
{
    public override void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using string: {0}", Prop);
    }
}

public class IntBase : GenericBase<int>
{
    public override void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using int: {0}", Prop);
    }
}
```

Basically I've added a generic class in the middle that stores your properly-typed property.  this will work assuming that you never need to access `Prop` from the code that iterates the members of the `List<Base>`.  (You could always add an abstract method to `Base` called `GetProp` that casts the generic to an object if that's required.)

Sample usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Base> l = new List<Base>();

        l.Add(new StrBase {Prop = "foo"});
        l.Add(new IntBase {Prop = 42});

        Console.WriteLine("Using each item");
        foreach (var o in l)
        {
            o.Use();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Added the GetProp() method to illustrate how the property can be directly accessed from the base class.

Comment: +1: This is a clean solution to the problem at hand. Separate out the base class from the generic part.

Answer (score 11):

You can't override the type of a property. Take a look at the following code:

```
StrBase s = new StrBase();
Base b = s;
```

This is completely valid code. But what happens when you try to do this?

```
b.prop = 5;
```

The integer can be converted to `object`, because everything is derived from `object`. But since `b` is actually a `StrBase` instance, it would have to convert the integer to a string somehow, which it can't. So that is why you aren't allowed to override the type.

The same principle applies to generics:

```
List<BaseG<object>> l = new List<BaseG<object>>();
BaseG<string> s = new BaseG<string>();

// The compiler will not allow this.
l.add(s);

// Here's the same problem, convert integer to string?
BaseG<object> o = l[0];
o.prop = 5;
```

This is because generic types in C# 2.0 are invariant. C# 4.0 does allow this type of conversions, called covariance and contravariance.

**Solutions**

An option is to cast the `object` back to string when you need it. You could add type validation in the subclass:

```
public class StrBase : Base
{
  private string propValue;

  public override object prop {
    get
    {
      return this.propValue;
    }
    set
    {
      if (value is string)
      {
        this.propValue = (string)value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also expose a type-safe property in the subclass:

```
public class StrBase : Base
{
  public string strProp {
    get
    {
      return (string)this.prop;
    }
    set
    {
      this.prop = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The simplicity of the first solution is attractive. Though, what happens if "prop" gets set with a different Type value? How would you look at this now 10 later? Anything new under the sun ;)

Comment: @BernoulliIT, I would probably reconsider the overall design, because I haven't really had the need for this ;) In my experience, code like this tends to come up when reading data structures that allow different value types, such as JSON. Usually it's better to just type properties as `object` and realize that you're sometimes dealing with data structures which are better left untyped. Trying to shoehorn it into the type system won't make it better, only more complicated.

Comment: How would you solve OP's problem using a covariant/contravariant approach?

Answer (score 5):

This is possible since **C# 9.0**

> Beginning with C# 9.0, override methods support covariant return types.

(see [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override))

Comment: Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) to co/contra-variance explanations

Comment: For properties this only works with **read-only** properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class First
{
    private int someV;

    public virtual object SomeV { get => someV; set => someV = (int)value; }

    public First() { }
}

public class Two : First
{
    private string someV;

    public override object SomeV { get => someV; set => someV = value.ToString(); }

    public Two() { }
}
```

and use of those:

```
First firstClass = new First();
firstClass.SomeV = 1;

Two twoClass = new Two();
twoClass.SomeV = "abcd";
```