# Refactoring two very similar classes into one

Tags: c#, refactoring

This is the first class:

```
public class TextBoxInt : TextBox
{
    public int min;
    public int max;

    public Value<int> value;

    public virtual void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int newValue;

        if (int.TryParse(Text, out newValue))
        {
            if (newValue < min || newValue > max)
            {
                //do thing A
            }

            value.Set(newValue);
            Text = value.Get().ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            Text = value.Get().ToString();
            Focus();
        }
    }

    public TextBoxInt(Value<int> value, int min, int max)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

        Text = value.Get().ToString();
        LostFocus += new EventHandler(update);
    }
}
```

This is the second class:

```
public class TextBoxFloat : TextBox
{
    public float min;
    public float max;

    public Value<float> value;

    public virtual void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float newValue;

        if (float.TryParse(Text, out newValue))
        {
            if (newValue < min || newValue > max)
            {
                //do thing A
            }

            value.Set(newValue);
            Text = value.Get().ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            Text = value.Get().ToString();
            Focus();
        }
    }

    public TextBoxFloat(Value<float> value, float min, float max)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

        Text = value.Get().ToString();

        LostFocus += new EventHandler(update);
    }
}
```

Also, this is the Value class :

```
public class Value<T>
{
    private T value;
    private List<IValueListener<T>> listeners = new List<IValueListener<T>>();

    public Value(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;

        foreach (IValueListener<T> listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.ValueUpdated(this);
        }
    }

    public void AddListener(IValueListener<T> listener)
    {
        listeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public void RemoveListener(IValueListener<T> listener)
    {
        listeners.Remove(listener);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first two classes are basically the same class. The only difference is the type. First one is `int`, the other one `float`. It seems that I would make for nicer code if I could combine those two into a single class.

I can set `min` and `max` to be floats and just cast them to `int` when needed if it's an int class. I'd just make sure I pass "whole" floats when the type is int.

Is there any way I can do it without duplicating `Update()` method (`If int do codeForInt, else if float do sameCodeButForFloat`)?

Also, even if I do duplicate the code, I run into a problem with `value.Set(newValue);` - in one case `newValue` would be `int`, in other it would be `float`, and I can't cast either to `T`.

Also, is there a way to limit the generic type? To specify it can only be int or a float?

Should I just leave them as two classes, or is there a way to unify them?

Comment: You'll might have more success on [codereview.se]

Comment: Did not know that existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making separate classes, you could make a generic class.

```
public class BoundedTextBox<T> : TextBox where T : IComparable<T> ...
```

Declaring that `T` implements `IComparable<T>` will allow you to check if `T` is in bounds during your set operation.

```
if (newValue.CompareTo(min) <= 0 || newValue.CompareTo(max) >= 0)
{
    // do thing A
}
```

Comment: It still leaves me the issue of `int.TryParse(Text, out newValue)`. If I use a large if and process int and float separately, I a) am using twice as much code I'd like to b) am unable to then use value.set(newValue) since newValue would then be int or float, not a generic type.

Comment: You can use a higher order function to cast the `string` into an `int` or `float` and keep it as a field within the `TextBox` class. This would be of type `Func<string, T>`.

Answer (score 1):

What about having an abstract `TextBox<T>` class inheriting from the `TextBox` class, where `TextBox<T>` has a new `abstract string GetValue()` method? You'll have `TextBoxFloat` class implementing `GetValue()` which will do the `float` specific logic and similarly will the `TextBoxInt` class. Your  `TextBox<T>` would be something like

```
public abstract class TextBox<T> : TextBox
{
    public T min;
    public T max;

    public Value<T> value;

    public virtual void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = GetValue();
        Focus();
    }

    public TextBoxFloat(Value<T> value, T min, T max)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

        Text = value.Get().ToString();
        LostFocus += new EventHandler(update);
    }

    public abstract string GetValue();
}
```

Comment: While it's cleaner than the setup I have right now, it just increases number of classes from two to three, although again, it reduces the amount of reused code. Valiant effort, but not really the answer I was looking for (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

As @flkes stated, a generic class is the way to go on this one. You could try something along these lines:                (you can find a fine example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141325/override-property-with-different-compatible-type/))

```
    public abstract class TextBoxBase
    {
        public abstract object GetMin();
        public abstract object GetMax();
        public abstract object GetValue();
    }

    public abstract class TextBox<T> : TextBoxBase
    {
        public T min { get; set; }
        public T max { get; set; }
        public T value { get; set; }
        public virtual void SetTextBox(T mn, T mx, T val)
        {
            min = mn;
            max = mx;
            value = val;
        }
        public override object GetMin() { return min; }
        public override object GetMax() { return max; }
        public override object GetValue() { return value; }
    }

    public class TextBoxInt : TextBox<int>
    {
        public override void SetTextBox(int mn, int mx, int val)
        {
            min = mn;
            max = mx;
            value = val;
        }
    }

    public class TextBoxFloat : TextBox<float>
    {
        public override void SetTextBox(float mn, float mx, float val)
        {
            min = mn;
            max = mx;
            value = val;
        }
    }
```